# Purchasing cell phone without warranty

Tags: warranties, phone

What does it mean when, for a consumer such as myself, purchasing say a Xiaomi phone without a warranty from Amazon? If it states returnable/refundable?

Why should it be a concern?

Comment: (This is not legal advice and I am not a lawyer)In the EU you have 2 years warranty.

Comment: In Australia the phone must work for a reasonable time. Fora phone that’s probably 4-5 years.

Answer (score 2):

It means that once the return period is over (whatever that might be, quite possibly not very long) you will have no legal remedy if the phone stops working or develops a problem. Whether this is an issue of concern is a matter of the buyer's judgement.

In some US state limited basic warranties are imposed by law, and cannot be disclaimed by a notice.